# How to write a select statement that tests two columns in a one-to-many table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two mysql tables in a one-to-many relationship.

```
Table a (id, title)
Table b (id, a_id, str1, str2)
```

I would like to select all of the rows from Table A, and include an additional column to indicate whether for every child row, if str1 is not null, str2 is also not null.

For example, given this data...

```
Table a (id, title)
1, row1
2, row2
3, row3
4, row4

Table 2 (id, a_id, str1, str2)
1, 2, testa, testb
2, 2, testc, NULL
3, 3, testd, teste
4, 4, NULL, NULL
```

...I would like to select a result set that looks something like this:

```
id, title, str1AndStr2
1, row1, 1
2, row2, 0
3, row3, 1
4, row4, 1
```

What is the best way to go about something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be accomplished using MySQL's [`case` statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html). For this use, I've inserted the case statement into your `select` clause to conditionally display a value.

```
select
  a.id
  , a.title
  , case 
    when b.str1 is not null and b.str2 is not null
      then 1
    else 0
  end as str1AndStr2
from
  tableA a
  join tableB b
```